Comparison Operators result in Python
Why in Python print(bool(7>8)==False==True) results False, logically it should be True?
as bool(7>8) is False, therefore
False==False==True  ->  True==True  ->  True (NOT False)
as the associativity is left to right.
The precedence of <,>,>=,<= are same as of ==, != or different?

Because it's "chained" to (False == False) and (False == True), not (False == False) == True.

Chaining aside, there is virtually never any reason to compare two Boolean values directly. x == True is equivalent to x, and x == False is equivalent to not x.

Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, for example:  x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).
